# Matplotlib | Python | Plotting figure A and then plotting another figure B on top of figure A

Tags: python, matplotlib

The fragment of code below plots a figure based on two arrays of floats

```
plt.scatter(t, h)
plt.xlabel("time")
plt.ylabel("height")
plt.show()
```

Then, after defining a function y(t), I need to add the following on top of the last plot:

```
plt.plot(t, y(t), 'r')
plt.show()
```

However, the code above generates two separate plots. I've noticed that if I comment out the first `plt.show()`, I'll get the second figure I am looking for. But is there a way to show them both?

I was expecting one plot and then another plot on top of the second one; however the second plot is shown as a new one

Answer (score 2):

`plt.show()` draws your figure on screen.

So, you need to remove the first `plt.show()` from your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the first plt.show() you should see the joint plot. The first plt.scatter just produces points on the joints of the line.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
t = np.random.random(10)
h = np.random.random(10)
plt.scatter(t, h)
plt.plot(t, h, 'r')
plt.show()
```

[The scatter plot is just the blue dots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xL7c.png)